# Monitoring SignalR Core message size

Tags: asp.net-core, prometheus, asp.net-core-signalr, signalrcore

I am looking for a way to monitor the exact size of each message sent through an aspnetCORE SignalR hub (both directions). I tried to use DI, middleware, HubDispatcher including inheriting IHubProtocol in HubConnectionContext since it seemed the most reasonable solution but had no result. All the other approaches I found may suit for the old SignalR but not for the netcore's one. Client's monitoring also won't do. Does someone have hands-on experience, at least using some Prometheus exporter?

Comment: Have you checked this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14247? HubDispather and DefaultHubDispatcher are now internal in 3.0

Comment: @FeiHan yes, but I thought that maybe there is a solution out of SignalR